# integration of a gaussian with $x^2$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I need to integrate
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^2 e^{-ax^2} \qquad \text{where } a\in R$$
The book does the following:

[image]

I don't understand what's happening. I tried solving the integral using integration by parts and this is what I got

$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^2 e^{-ax^2} &= x^2\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}} - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}} 2x dx  && \text{as we are told } \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx e^{-ax^2}= \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}\\
&=x^2\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}} - 2\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}\frac{x^2}{2} && \text{as } \int xdx = \frac{x^2}{2} \\
&= 0
\end{align}
$$

What am I doing wrong?

Actually, I might have found a way of solving this

$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^2 e^{-ax^2} dx &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x\cdot x e^{-ax^2} dx \\
&= - \frac{1}{2a} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  x(-2ax)e^{-ax^2} dx \\
&= -\frac{1}{2a}\left(\left[e^{-ax^2}\right]_{-\infty}^{\infty} - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-ax2} dx\right) \\
&= -\frac{1}{2a}\left(0 - \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2a}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I am using $x^2$ as the first term, and $e^{-a x^2}$ as the second one. I am integrating $e^{-a x^2}$ in the integration by parts.

Comment: well, you figured it out the very moment I posted my answer. Must have been telepathy. Happens all the time to me...;-) +1 for figuring it out yourself.

Comment: @Euler_Salter, just one small thing to point out: even if your final answer is correct, you missed an $x$ in front of $e^{-ax^2}$ in the third equality (the one after you apply integration by parts). It would be nice if you edited this in case others want to follow it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

note that the derivative of $e^{-ax^2}$ is $-2ax e^{-ax^2}$, so
$$ x^2 e^{-ax^2} = \frac{-1}{2a}x \,(-2ax e^{-ax^2}) = \frac{-1}{2a}x\, \frac{d}{dx} e^{-ax^2}$$

Insert this into the integral and integrate by parts.

Answer (score 2):

Good job for identifying the components used for integration by parts.

If you are familiar with normal distribution, here's an intepretation for $a>0$,

Let $\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}=a$

\begin{align}\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2 \exp(-ax^2) \, dx &=\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}x^2 \exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}\right) \, dx\\
&= \sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}\left(\sigma^2+0^2 \right)\\
&=\frac1{2a}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}\end{align}

where I have used the property that $Var(X)=E(X^2)-E(X)^2$